# Searching, return a distinct list of classes that the students are in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am building an ASP.NET MVC app using C#. I have two Azure SQL tables, `Students` and `Classes`.

I have built the search functionality to search classes and return the results.

Now I need to through students into the mix. I would like to search students using `.Contains` and return a distinct list of classes that the students are in.

For example:

STUDENTS

[image: Students Table Screenshot]

CLASSES

[image: Classes Table Screenshot]

- If I search for "Tom", then Computer Engineering and Data Science are returned.
- If I search for "Chris", then Computer Engineering and Data Science are returned.
- If I search for "Bill", then Computer Engineering is returned.

No duplicate class names should be returned.

Here is the code snippet in my controller as it stands.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
    var classes = from m in _context.ClassesClass
                  select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        classes = classes.Where(s => s.CLASS_NAME.Contains(searchString));
    }

    return View(await classes.ToListAsync());
}
```

How do I approach this?

Comment: So maybe you need to get all class names of students that their names contains `"ant"` for example?

Comment: Please provide your sample data as valid C# code, not screenshots. We can't develop and test with screenshots.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for the feedback, I need all I can get. Do you have an example of something you'd be looking for?

Comment: For what I understand on your question, what you need is Student table join Class table and perform the filter.

Comment: @YongShun if I run this in sql:
SELECT 

C.[CLASS_NAME]
      
  FROM [dbo].[CLASSES] as C
  JOIN [dbo].[STUDENTS] as S ON C.CLASS_ID=S.CLASS_ID

  WHERE S.NAME like '%TOM%'

Will return duplicate class names. Am I missing something?

Comment: @twhite54 - `var classes =  new [] { new { class_id =1 } };`. Start with that.

Answer (score 0):

If your entities are setup correctly with the relationship, your query should look something like:

```
var classes = await _context.Students.Where(s => s.Contains(searchString)).Select(s => s.Class.CLASS_NAME).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

Your table structure isn't nice as each student should have one record and the joining of students and classes should be in a separate joining table, e.g.:

```
STUDENTCLASSES
| StudentID  | ClassID |
| ---------- | ------- |
| 1          | 1       |
| 1          | 2       |
| 2          | 1       |
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the result returning a duplicate of the class, you need to group by expression.

```cs
var students = _context.Students
    .AsQueryable();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    students = students.Where(s => s.StudentName.Contains(searchString));
}

var classes = (from a in students
        join b in _context.ClassesClass on a.ClassId equals b.ClassId
        group b by b.ClassId into g
        select g.Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault()
    ).ToList();
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BOZ7ox)